# Getting rid of Outer Nested Observable Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am currently trying to get rid of an Outer Observable.  My current code creates an `Observable<Observable<any>[]>` but I am trying to get an `Observable<any>[]` type.  I've played around with different rxjs operators but couldn't find any that would work.  I believe part of my problem is with outer map but I'm not sure how to change that without loosing my inner array.

So I have this code

```
this.userOrgs = this.db.doc(user_preferences/${user.uid}).valueChanges().pipe(
  map((pref: UserPreferences) => {
    return pref.orgs.map(org => {
      return this.db.doc(organizations/${org}).valueChanges().pipe(
        map((o: Organization) => { return o; })
      );
    });
  })
);
```

and this.userOrgs is of type `Observable<Organization>[]`;

Comment: I believe you're looking for mergeMap https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html

Comment: I've tried that but it gets rid of my array of Observables which I want to keep.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: So Im trying to get an `Observable<Organization>[]` object but my current code returns a Double Observable.  I only care about The Organization and after my first usage of the outer Observable I don't need it after I get a value from it in the future.

Comment: Then reduce (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/reduce.html) might be what you're looking for. If that doesn't work, likely what you'll have to do: 

If you're certain your outer observable will emit only once, use the `take` operator to `take(1)` which will complete your outer observable once you're subscribed to it once and it has delivered it's first value. inside that subscription, operate on your inner observable. If you need to, you can set a variable outside of all of it before you make your first call. and read all the values from the inner observable there.

Comment: I take all of that back. Use `toPromise` on the outer observable and then either `await` it or use `.then` to run the rest of your code. Converting observable that deliver only one value to promises and awaiting them makes the code much easier to reason about

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html

Comment: Why don't you just subscribe to get to the array in the Observable? (Your code doesn't return a double Observable as you say, I guess you meant Observable within an Observable. It returns an Observable of an array.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain what library you're using but the result should look something like this

```
public async getOrganizations(user: any): Observable<Organization>[] {
    const pref: UserPreferences = await this.db.doc(user_preferences/${user.uid}).valueChanges().toPromise();

    return pref.orgs.map(org => {
      return this.db.doc(organizations/${org}).valueChanges().pipe(map((o: Organization) => {
        return o;
      }));
    });
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `.subscribe()` in the second line.